How was this equation for the stability of a finite difference model Wave Equation derived? Von Neumann analysis?
Wave Equation
In this paper, the following equation is given for a wave equation:



Stability Equation
They then go on to state the stability of such a wave equation in sample based solutions (in terms of space step $Δx = h$ here and time step $Δt = \frac{1}{f_s} = k$) is given by the following:



However no explanation is given for how this is solved. The only reference points to "S. Bilbao, Numerical Sound Synthesis, J. Wiley & Sons, 2009." which is a textbook I bought based on this in the hopes it would explain it. However, certainly no direct explanation is given and most of that book is sadly way over my head.
Question
I am wondering if anyone understands how this stability equation was derived and if they could please share or explain it. This is something that has puzzled me now for years.
Understanding how it was derived may allow me to solve other similar wave equation stability conditions.
I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks for any help.

Reply to (Partial) Answer:
Thank you very much for this clear and simple explanation. From what I can see, there are then three gaps. Two I think I understand and one I don't. I would appreciate any further thoughts:
1) $σ_0=0$ assumption
I believe $σ_0=0$ is used here because this is a simple velocity damping force (like viscous drag) on each element of the wave equation, and it generally represents a stabilizing influence on the wave equation. I am guessing they did not want that in their calculation for stability because they wanted to be able to set it as low as $0$ or as high as whatever without it affecting the stability or requiring a new time/space step. The equation is least stable at $σ_0=0$ so this was used.
2) $κ$ sign issue
Based on your post, I actually suspect there is an error in the publication regarding the sign. Your sign for that $κ$ term makes sense based on your steps. I have followed your derivation as well and that is what you get.
Though perhaps we are still missing something re: point (3) below.
3) $∂_t \sim {2\over k}$ and $∂_x \sim {2 \over h}$ assumption
The only thing then I don't follow entirely is this: $$∂_t u \simeq \frac{u(t+k) - u(t)}{k} \quad \longrightarrow \quad ∂_t \sim {2 \over k},$$
and likewise $∂_x \sim {2 \over h}$. Certainly I understand the $∂_tu \simeq \frac{u(t+k) - u(t)}{k}$ part but not how that got the $∂_t \sim {2 \over k}$.
Last Question:
Can you (or anyone) think of any reason for why this substitution in point (3) above was done? Where might the $2$ have come from? Thanks again.

The same question was crossposted to MSE ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4962743/how-was-this-equation-for-the-stability-of-a-finite-difference-model-wave-equati ). While cross-posting is not forbidden, there are good reasons to include a link to the other question  on the other site (see in particular https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu )

Here is some partial answer that misses some steps/info to be complete and rigorous, but should be enough to explain the derivation. Firstly, since $\sigma_0$ doesn't appear in the formula, I'll assume there is some context/physical hypothesis that allows to take $\sigma_0 = 0$. The dynamics are then described by:
$$\left(\partial_t^2 + \kappa^2\partial_x^4 - c^2\partial_x^2 - 2\sigma_1\partial_t\partial_x^2\right)u = 0.$$
The discretization comes from taking $t = nk$, $x = lh$ where $k$ and $h$ are the discretization spacings. So the partial derivatives can rouhgly be thought as some numbers:
$$\partial_tu \simeq \frac{u(t+k) - u(t)}{k} \quad \longrightarrow \quad \partial_t \sim {2 \over k},$$
and likewise $\partial_x \sim {2 \over h}$. The exact substitution depends on the discretization model. Inserting these formal substitutions in the dynamical equation yields:
$${4u \over k^2} + \kappa^2{16u \over h^4} - c^2{4u \over h^2} - 2\sigma_1{8u \over kh^2} = 0.$$
We look for non-zero solutions so we can simplify by $u$, and multiply the overall equality by $h^4k^2/4$ to get a biquadratic equation in $h$ (a fancy way to say it's a quadratic equation in $h^2$):
$$h^4 - h^2(k^2c^2 + 4\sigma_1k) + 4k^2\kappa^2 = 0,$$
whose  solutions are
$$h_{\min} = \pm\sqrt{k^2c^2 + 4\sigma_1k \pm \sqrt{(k^2c^2 + 4\sigma_1k)^2 - 16k^2\kappa^2} \over 2}.$$
The formula you showed has exactly the same look, less the $\pm$ signs to account for the positivity of the solution, and with a different sign next to $16\kappa^2k^2$. I assume the specifics of the discretization process will explain this difference. It should also justify the factor $2$ in the substitued partial derivative operators I provided (and that I added to get the final coefficients right). A
The takeaway is that the solution from the article is a quadratic formula in $h_\min$ that most likely originates from the fact only operators $\partial_x^2$ and $\partial_x^4$ are present in the dynamics. Based on the overall sign of the bi-quadratic equation, $h_\min$ value is the only real, positive value that minimizes the error of a trial discretized function $u$ with respect to the discretized dynamics.

Thank you very much! That gets us very close to the finish line and makes perfect sense! I appreciate it. I updated my question with a detailed response. I think the omission of the $σ_0$ makes sense, and the sign of the $κ$ term is correct in yours and not theirs. (Ie. I think they made a mistake there.) Which just leaves trying to explain the $2$ in the $∂_t∼{2\over k}$. Any further thoughts or guesses on that one? Thanks again either way.

Again, a partial answer, justifying a bit Pitchoune answer. This is, I think, a basic Von-Neuman analysis. Discretize the equation according to the discretization given in the article (be wary of some typos):
$$\frac{1}{k^2} \left( u_l^{n+1} - 2u_l^n + u_l^{n-1} \right) = c^2  \frac{1}{h^2} \left( u_{l+1}^n - 2u_l^n + u_{l-1}^n \right) - \kappa^2  \frac{1}{h^4} \left( u_{l+2}^n - 4u_{l+1}^n + 6u_l^n - 4u_{l-1}^n + u_{l-2}^n \right)
- \frac{2\sigma_0}{2k} \left( u_l^{n+1} - u_l^{n-1} \right) + \frac{2\sigma_1}{h^2k} \left( u_{l+1}^{n} - 2u_l^{n} + u_{l-1}^{n} - u_{l+1}^{n-1} + 2u_l^{n-1} - u_{l-1}^{n-1} \right)\tag 1
$$
Then, put an Ansatz: $u_{l}^n=\zeta^n e^{i l K h}$. Which is basically a plane wave with wavevector $K$. A necessary condition for the stability of the algorithm is that $|\zeta(K)|\leq 1$ so that the amplitude of the wave does not blow up with time.
We put this Ansatz in (1) and obtain:
$$
6 \zeta k^2 \kappa^2 + (-1 + \zeta) h^4 \left(-1 + \zeta + (1 + \zeta) k \sigma_0 \right) + 
2 h^2 k \left(c^2 \zeta k + 2 (-1 + \zeta) \sigma_1 \right) - 
2 k \left(c^2 \zeta h^2 k + 4 \zeta k \kappa^2 + 
2 (-1 + \zeta) h^2 \sigma_1 \right) \cos(h K) + 
2 \zeta k^2 \kappa^2 \cos(2 h K)
=0\tag 2
$$
Well now, we're a bit stuck because we would need to solve this equation for $\zeta$. Unfortunately, it's a pain. Thus, we simply put $\zeta = \pm 1$, which should gives us the limiting $h$ or $k$. The most restrictive case (plus or minus) will be the one  that we chose. You have the same problem for $K$. You have to take the $K$ that leads to the most restrictive condition possible. Since we know the result does not contain square root. It seems alright to guess that the worst case scenario is either $K=0$ or $K=\pm \pi/2h$. With trial and error, you find that the most restrictive scenario (the one that leads first to an instability) is for $\zeta = -1$ and $K=-\pi/2h$. If you put this into the equation (2):
$$h^4-4k^2\kappa^2-2h^2k(c^2k-4\sigma_1)=0 \tag 3$$
Which can be solve and leads to:
$$h = \sqrt{c^2k^2+\sigma_1k+\sqrt{16k^2\kappa^2+(c^2k^2 +4k\sigma_1)^2}}/2$$
which is almost what you want (up to a factor $\sqrt{2}$), which is either an issue in the choice of discretization or in the choice of $K$.
Edit: A primer on Von-Neuman analysis.
To understand a bit more clearly the technique, let's start from a simpler wave equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\tag a$$
The discretized version is:
$$\frac{1}{k^2} \left( u_l^{n+1} - 2u_l^n + u_l^{n-1} \right)=c^2  \frac{1}{h^2} \left( u_{l+1}^n - 2u_l^n + u_{l-1}^n \right) \tag b$$
Now, you want to find whether this equation can lead to an instability (only due to the discretization). An instability means that some term diverges. It's a linear equation thus it seems appropriate to try to see what happens for a plane wave perturbation. That is, how will a plane wave perturbation evolve with time. The plane wave perturbation takes the form:
$$u_{l}^n=\zeta^n e^{i l K h}\tag c$$
The time evolution on $\zeta^n$ is directly an assumption on the possible decay or growth of the perturbation. We make the assumption that it can either decay or growth exponentially.
If $|\zeta|<1$, with time $|\zeta|^n\to 0$ as $n$ becomes large. Which means that the pertubation does not explode! Which is what we want, hence the stability of the discretization requires that $|\zeta|<1$. To obtain this $\zeta$ a simple thing to do is to put (c) in (b):
\begin{split}  
u_l^{n+1} &= 2u_l^n - u_l^{n-1}+c^2  \frac{k^2}{h^2} \left( u_{l+1}^n - 2u_l^n + u_{l-1}^n \right) \\
\Rightarrow \zeta^{n+1}e^{ilKh} &=2\zeta^{n}e^{ilKh}-\zeta^{n-1}e^{ilKh} + c^2  \frac{k^2}{h^2} \left(\zeta^{n}e^{i(l+1)Kh} - 2\zeta^{n}e^{ilKh}+\zeta^{n}e^{i(l-1)Kh}\right)\\
\Rightarrow \zeta &=2-\zeta^{-1} + c^2  \frac{k^2}{h^2} \left(e^{iKh} - 2+e^{-iKh}\right)
\end{split}
Finally, we obtain the following equation for $\zeta$:
$$\zeta^2-\zeta \underbrace{2(1+(ck/h)^2\left(\cos(Kh)-1\right))}_{\mu} + 1 = 0$$
This second order equation has the solution:
$$\zeta=(\mu/2)\pm \sqrt{(\mu/2)^2-1}$$
The real part of $\zeta$ ($|\zeta|$) is lower than 1 if $|\mu/2|<1$, which requires:
$$-1<1+(ck/h)^2\left(\cos(Kh)-1\right)<1$$
As you can see, different $K$ leads to different stability conditions (some wavelenght can be stable and some not). Worst case scenario is $\cos(Kh)=-1$, in which case the most restrictive condition is:
$$(ck/h)^2<1$$
which is the usual relation.
Note that, in the case above, we could not solve the equation for $\zeta$ exactly so we put it to $\zeta=1$ in order to obtain the point at which it destabilizes.

Thanks Syrocco! I have been trying to understand Von Neumann analysis for years but I still can't follow it. I understand your equation (1) obviously. I understand also how you went from (2) to (3). I don't however understand how you made (2) or what this means: $u_{l}^n=\zeta^n e^{i l K h}$ or $ζ(K)$. Can you explain those in simple human terms or what each parameter/variable is here? And how does putting that in (1) lead to (2)? Even just one or two extra steps between (1) and (2) would be very helpful if you're willing.

I believe what you are saying with the Ansatz is "we substitute in for the position of $u$ the fourier modes for a basic plain wave equation as a rough assumption." Like the equation (3) or (4) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis But even if so, I still don't know how that works in terms of creating equation (2). I would like to know though. Thanks for any help if so.

To be clear, I want to be able to go from other versions of equation (1) ie working from other discretized string wave equations which are also variants of the basic $y_{tt} = c^2y_{xx}$ (with other terms) to equation (3) and stability conditions for those also, so I'm trying to understand stepwise how to do this.

@mike I edited the answer at the end
